# Represent CURL code in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I have this code that represents a curl code:

```
curl -X PUT https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/794 \
    -u consumer_key:consumer_secret \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{
  "regular_price": "24.54"
}'
```

I need to represent this same CURL code using PHP, for this I try the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/794');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-Type: application/json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

**-H** is supposed to be the header, but what are **-u** and **-d** and how can I send them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-u` is for Authorization header

```
$encodedAuth = base64_encode("consumer_key:consumer_secret");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization : Basic ".$encodedAuth));
```

or using this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "consumer_key:consumer_secret");
```

`-d` is for data or request body

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"regular_price":"24.54"}');
```

you also need to set custom request method for `PUT`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
```